# Login verification not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3, session-state

Hello,
so I built a login system in CodeIgniter in which 3 verification's steps are/should be met with the database before being allowed to access to the specific pages.

The three steps values are: `active`, `is_member` and `is_admin`

This is the code that I made in my Users controller:

```
public function login(){
    // Prohibit access if already logged in
    $this->User_model->session_comprobate_member();

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required|min_length[4]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|min_length[4]');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        //Load View Into Template
        $this->template->load('public','login','users/login');
    } else {
       // Get Post Data from Database
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $enc_password = md5($password);
        $data_user = $this->User_model->login($username, $enc_password);

        if($data_user == true){
            $user_id = $this->User_model->get_userid($username);
            $users   = $this->User_model->get_username($user_id);

            if($users->active == 0){

            // Create error
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'This account is banned or inactive');

            // Redirect to page
            redirect('dashboard/login');

            }

            if($users->is_admin == 0){

            // Create error
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'You do not have permission to view this page');

            // Redirect to page
            redirect('dashboard/login');

            }

            if($users->is_member == 0){

            // Create error
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'This account does not exists. Please try again.');

            // Redirect to page
            redirect('dashboard/login');

            } else {
            $sess_data = array(
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'username'  => $username,
                'occupation' => 'occupation',
                'is_member' => true,
                'is_admin' => true,
                'active' => true
            );

            // Set Session Data
            $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);

            // Create Message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'You are logged in');

            // Redirect to pages
            redirect('dashboard');
            }
        } else {
            // Create Error
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Login');

            // Redirect to pages
            redirect('dashboard/login');
        }
    }
}
```

Each of these values are set to `TRUE(1)` or `FALSE(0)` depending on the user account.
I have an account with the tree values equal to 1 so it should allow me to access; here is a picture:
[image: Database images showing values set to true or false]
What I want is to be allowed to access after the login verification has met the three values

but for some reason even after having the user with all set to `TRUE` if just keeps throwing me the first error that I created:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'This account is banned or inactive');
```

Any idea how to fix it?
Thanks.

Here is my model:

```
    public function get($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
        return $query->row();
    }    
public function login($username, $password)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->row()->id;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //I need to work on these two
    public function get_username($users) {
        $this->db->select('id');
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('username', $users);
        return $this->db->get()->row;
    }

    public function get_userid($user_id) {
        $this->db->select('id');
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('id', $user_id);
        return $this->db->get()->row();
    }
    ///
    //Check if admin
    public function is_admin($id) {
        $this->db->select('is_admin');
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $is_admin = $this->db->get()->row('is_admin');
        if ($is_admin == 0) {
            redirect('/');
        } else {
            redirect('admin');
        }
    }

    //Check if member
    public function is_member($id) {
        $this->db->select('is_member');
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $is_member = $this->db->get()->row('is_member');
        if ($is_member == 0) {
            redirect('/');
        } else {
            redirect('dashboard/login');
        }
    }

    //Check if active
    public function is_active($id) {
        $this->db->select('active');
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $is_active = $this->db->get()->row('active');
        if ($is_active == 0) {
            redirect('/');
        } else {
            redirect('dashboard/login');
        }
    }
```

Again thanks for the help.

Comment: print '$users' and verify the returned fields . i think only id is returned not other fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming `username` is **unique** column in table:

**Controller**

```
// user login
if($data_user == true) {

    // $username from $this->input->post('username');
    // call model function
    $user = $this->User_model->get_username($username);

    // is active user ?
    if($user['active'] == 0) {

        // Create error
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'This account is banned or inactive');

        // Redirect to page
        redirect('dashboard/login');

    }

    // is admin ?
    if($user['is_admin'] == 0) {

        // Create error
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'You do not have permission to view this page');

        // Redirect to page
        redirect('dashboard/login');

    }

    // is member ?
    if($user['is_member'] == 0) {

        // Create error
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'This account does not exists. Please try again.');

        // Redirect to page
        redirect('dashboard/login');

    } else {

        $sess_data = array(
            'user_id' => $user['id'],
            'username'  => $user['username'],
            'occupation' => 'occupation',
            'is_member' => true,
            'is_admin' => true,
            'active' => true
        );

        // Set Session Data
        $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);

        // Create Message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'You are logged in');

        // Redirect to pages
        redirect('dashboard');
    }

} else {

    // Create Error
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Login');

    // Redirect to pages
    redirect('dashboard/login');
}
```

this model for `get_username()`

```
public function get_username($username) {

    // select field we needed
    $this->db->select('id', 'username', active, is_admin, is_member);
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->limit(1);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    // check is $query have a data ?
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

        // return data
        return $query->row_array();

    } else {

        // redirect login, because no data with that username
        redirect('dashboard/login');

    } 
}
```

Comment: is still not working and I actually tried by selecting all(*) in the model but still is just not working :/. Yes, my username is unique

Comment: hey its working now, thanks I just changed some stufff in your code. I'm marking your answer as the right one.

Answer (score 0):

In your `get_username()` in model you are selecting only id and in controller you are checking values in active column. Add active column in `get_username()` selection.